# Two-row-plot formatting

Tags: r, formatting, plot, rows

I have the following problem:
I want to make a plot in R where two figures are above each other. However, the upper figure should take up most of the space and the lower figure should just have a very low height (it just serves to indicate special positions in the "main" figure). At the moment I have this code, but I don't know how to set the space each row should take up (and 
the second plot should be immediately beneath the first one):

```
dev.new()
png("multitest.png")
par( mfrow = c( 2, 1 ) ) 
plot( rnorm( n = 10 ), col = "blue", main = "plot 1", cex.lab = 1.1,ylab="yname", xlab='')
plot( rnorm( n = 10 ), col = "red", main = "", cex.lab = 1.1, xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab="xname", ylab="")
dev.off()
```

I have to run it on a server where I don't know if additional packages are available for R. If there is a suggestions using additional packages, I will try it though.
Thank you in advance, I have used plots in R just for simple histograms so far.

Comment: @Roland, why not add this as an answer?

Comment: @mrdwab, because I'm afraid I would get another "Enlightened" badge for that.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, it was hard to find a good explanation how the matrix parameter works, though.

Comment: @user1448268, I hope my explanation helped you understand how to use the matrix argument. It can be quite powerful when laying out complicated sets of graphs in different sizes (and sometimes, I've found that actually drawing my layout on paper first can help me figure out the correct matrix that I would need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use layout:

```
nf <- layout( c( 1, 2 ), heights= c( 10, 2 ) )
plot( ... )
plot( .... )
```

The first argument is a matrix that mimicks how your screen is divided (here we have a vector as an argument, but you could use `matrix( c( 1, 2 ), nrow=2, ncol=1 )`.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me. Using "heights=c(2,1)", it looks almost perfect now, but the problem is that there is still a lot of white space between the plots (maybe because I just set the x-label of the upper plot and title of the lower plot to "" ?)

Comment: @user1448268: In an @Roland style answer, see "`mai`" in `?par`.

Comment: `mai` or `mar`; the default `mar` is `c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1` (in terms of lines of text), and this is plenty.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now what's left is to reduce the space between the xlabel and the plot. But I hope I can figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by @Roland, `layout()` would be much better for this purpose than using `par(mfrow...)`. Here are some basic examples to show you how to get started with `layout`. None of these examples do the work for you: I'm just giving examples so you can figure out how to experiment with it. A useful function here is also `layout.show()`.

1. Two plots, one above the other. The first plot is wider than the other.

   First, think of a matrix of how you want your figures to appear. Number them sequentially. `1` = Figure 1, `2` = Figure 2, `0` = Nothing plotted in this space.

   ```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
   [1,]    1    1    1    1
   [2,]    0    2    2    0
   ```

   Use this matrix in `layout()`:

   ```
   layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0), 2, 4, byrow=TRUE))
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "blue", main = "plot 1", 
        cex.lab = 1.1, ylab="yname", xlab='')
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "red", main = "", cex.lab = 1.1, 
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="xname", ylab="")
   ```

   [image]
2. Notice that the heights of each plot is still the same. You can use the `heights` argument to control for this:

   ```
   layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0), 2, 4, byrow=TRUE), 
          heights = c(7, 3))
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "blue", main = "plot 1", 
        cex.lab = 1.1, ylab="yname", xlab='')
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "red", main = "", cex.lab = 1.1, 
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="xname", ylab="")
   ```

   [image]
3. Here is an example with three plots.

   ```
   layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE))
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "blue", main = "plot 1", 
        cex.lab = 1.1, ylab="yname", xlab='')
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "red", main = "", cex.lab = 1.1, 
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="xname", ylab="")
   plot(rnorm(n = 10), col = "green", main = "", cex.lab = 1.1, 
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="zname", ylab="")
   ```

   [image]